# Adding event to the calendar with apple watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

One of our requirements is to allow the user to add a specific date/time that is recurring/nonrecurring to the calendar by using the watch.

What is best practice for doing this?

Should I send the parameters to the parent with `WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication` and have the phone add the event?

Or is it preferable to have the actual watch add the event to the calendar? Which means importing the `EKEventStore` in the watchkit extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´d say it doesn´t make quite of a difference right now, but to be ready for future watch hardware and maybe having the possiblity to add a calendar entry without having the phone connected to the watch, I´d choose to run EventKit directly in the watch code.

But I guess the biggest problem you will face is the interface to choose the date! How are you gonna do that? There is no date picker yet in WatchKit, so you will have to do it yourself.

Remember: every piece of code is executed on the phone, not on the watch. So for every button you touch and process, the watch has to communicate back and forth with the phone via Bluetooth. This maybe won´t lead to a smooth and responsive user interface.

Another chance to get this functionality would be Siri, I guess. And then, you don´t have to do anything, I assume, as Siri can connect to the Calendar directly.